# Post Message From AWS Lambda Service to GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-pubsub

I am posting message to GCP Pub/Sub from AWS Lambda.
I am using the Client Libraries to do this work as mentioned in the google documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher

When Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 is added via Nuget, it internally adds the below libraries to the solution
`libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so - Approximately 80MB`

`libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so - Approximately 67MB`

While publishing the AWS Lambda application from Visual Studio 2019, error is thrown because of the upload limit (50MB) .
Published folder size is more than 50MB even after the folder is zipped.

As a Workaround, I manually deleted the `libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so` file from the publish folder and removed that reference also from
`.deps.json` file and upload the zip file to Lambda.

Is there any easier way of achieving this task? I am not sure if I missed any option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [API call](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish) if the libraries can't be installed. You still need to have OAuth2 library to generate an access to put in the header of the request. But the Google OAuth2 lib should be smaller than the big one that you try to install.

Answer (score 0):

## S3 Bypass

First create the function with any random zip file under 50MB.  For my command I'm assuming your function name is *limits-test* and your functions deployment package is called *function.zip*.

Then create an s3 bucket

```
aws s3 mb s3://limits-test--region us-east-1
```

Upload your function's deployment package

```
aws s3 cp ./function.zip s3://limits-bucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.zip"
```

Then update your function to point to s3

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name limits-test --region us-east-1 --s3-bucket limits-bucket --s3-key function.zip
```

This will bypass the 50MB limit.  The limit is now 250MB I believe